# PHP numberformatter::parse truncates decimals

Tags: php, locale, numberformatter

I'm having a problem with my code where NumberFormatter::parse() is truncating decimals when there is a trailing zero.  Our app uses Intl to be locale aware, so I am doing a JSON API call to check to make sure a number entered in a form is actually a number.  For example when the locale calls for a comma as a decimal separator return FALSE for numbers entered with a period.

```
function parse_decimals($number)
{
    // ignore empty strings and return
    if(empty($number))
    {
    return $number;
    }

    $config    = get_instance()->config;
    $fmt       = new \NumberFormatter( $config->item('number_locale'), \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

    $fmt->format(1234567890.12300);

    if (empty($config->item('thousands_separator')))
    {
        $fmt->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '');
    }

    try
    {
        if(strcmp(strval($fmt->parse($number)),strval($number)) != 0)
        {
            $number = FALSE;
        }
        return $fmt->parse($number);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The locale doesn't matter (because it's happeneing with all locales, so for the sake of argument Intl is used to set the locale to en_US.

Entered 50.00
Expected 50.00
Actual 50
Return Result FALSE

So you can see that parse is truncating 50.00 to 50.  I have tried playing around with `NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS`, `NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS` and `NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS` without any effect.  A side note is that if there is a better way to compare the expected number's format with the entered number's format than this, please feel free to suggest something better than this:

```
if(strcmp(strval($fmt->parse($number)),strval($number)) != 0)
{
    $number = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Real _numbers_ do not have such trailing zeroes after the decimal point. You are confusing the _formatted representation_ of a number, with the actual number. _“So you can see that parse is truncating 50.00 to 50”_ - nothing wrong with that, works as designed, _everything else_ would be wrong. If you want to _show_ this value again as `50.00` - then you _format_ it accordingly at the time you are outputting it.

Comment: OK, I hear you but I still need to be able to compare the originally entered number with the locale specific version and keep the precision.  Do I need to resort to using preg_match with regex to do this or is there another way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: _Format_ your parsed number value to the specific format again, and compare with the original string input value ...

Comment: The problem is that when I change the if statement to `if(strcmp(strval($fmt->format($fmt->parse($number))),strval($number)) != 0)` it still doesn't match with decimals.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to also add `$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS,2);` because it wasn't set by default from PHP Intl.

Comment: So, now that I have added the FRACTION_DIGITS,2 it does correct the issue of formatting the decimal so that it matches but now entering a value without a decimal and fraction fails checks (e.g., 50) because my reformatting of the parsed value is forcing it to two decimals when the original value had none.  What I would like is to reliably not truncate the decimal regardless of whether there is trailing zeros or not.  I understand the mathematical nuance yet it's still not desired in this case.

Comment: _"What I would like is to reliably not truncate the decimal regardless of whether there is trailing zeros or not."_ - then you don't want to work with numbers, but validate and treat your input as text strings.